# Enabling Stackdriver Debugging in Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: docker, kubernetes, .net-core, google-kubernetes-engine, pdb-files

I am struggling in enabling Stackdriver Debugging in Kubernetes Engine. The documentation is here: https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/dotnet

What does it mean by *"When building the .NET Core application, be sure to add and deploy PDB files with your code"*? And how do I go about doing this?

Also, what does it mean by *"Use a custom Dockerfile"*? And how do I go about doing this. I've found this documentation slightly vague.

Thanks!

Comment: Program Database (PDB) is a companion file used by Microsoft runtimes to provide debugging information. The PDB is important because it enables Stackdriver Debugging to provide richer information about your code. [link: https://www.wintellect.com/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know]

Comment: The custom Dockerfile is the one shown below the text. You'll note that it uses an image `aspnetcore` from a repository that specifically references `debugger` (`dotnet-debugger`). I assume (have not tried) that this image is a variant of the regular image that adds debugging capabilities. Were you able to get this to work? I'm intrigued and may find some time to try this out too.

Comment: So do I have to create a PDB file? How do I do that? How do I “use” the socket file? I am very new to kubernetes

Comment: This isn't a Kubernetes technology, it's a Microsoft technology. I recommend you Google PDB and .NET to find instructions on how to create these. If you're using Visual Studio, it's probably trivial. Either way, it should be straightforward.

Comment: Will do. What about the docker file? How do I implement that?

Comment: You can use the Dockerfile provided in the documentation. Tweak if necessary for your app, build it (`docker build --tag....`), push it (`docker push...`) and then reference that image from your Kubernetes deployment manifest.

Comment: If I reference that image, will it replace my current image?

Comment: You should (!) be able to replace the `FROM` image with the google-provided image in your Dockerfile and generate (I recommend) a differently named Docker image that you would then test (locally) and deploy to Kubernetes. In trying this for you, I receive errors. I'm going to file a bug and see whether I can help you resolve the issue. Were you able to make any progress otherwise?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I have resorted to having to delpoy the application each time I make a modification and test if it works. This is very laborious as it would be far quicker to be able to debug my code with breakpoints etc. I do however, get notifications from Stackdriver Error Reporting which makes me believe that there must be some way for me to be able to write to whatever Stackdriver Error Reporting is reading from. This would help debugging massively if possible.

Comment: For example `System.InvalidOperationException: Queue is full
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.BufferedClientStreamWriter"1.ValidateStateForWrite(Boolean throwOnError, Boolean isCompletion)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.BufferedClientStreamWriter"1.WriteAsyncImpl(T message, WriteOptions options, Boolean modifyOptions, Boolean throwOnError)
   at telebot_pianomoves_v1.Program.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<<Main>b__4>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\hjstu\Desktop\Telebot\Visual_Studio\Telebot-pianomoves-v1\telebot-pianomoves-v1\telebot-pianomoves-v1\Program.cs:line 152` Stackdriver Error Reporting gives the line too.

Comment: Engineering is going to look into the issue I had swapping the `FROM` image with the Google-provided debugger image (`gcr.io/dotnet-debugger/aspnetcore:2.1`). I'm headed out on vacation but will have someone update you once this is done. You should then be able to swap that image in to your Dockerfile, build it and reference that from your Kubernetes configs.

Comment: Much appreciated! I look forward to the update. Thanks

Comment: Please could you either add a way of reproducing the problem within this question, or file an issue in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet-debugger with more context? (It would be easier to have a conversation in an issue than in a comment thread here on SO, although we'll want to update this question and potentially answer it when we've got to the bottom of it.)